# Why is video onplay event not firing sometimes when the video begins the first time after reloading?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-video

I am creating a chrome extension that will automatically pause a youtube video when I switch to another youtube video tab. I am using onplay event to trigger a message to the background script to pause the currently playing video in the unfocused tab. The problem is it only works like 50% of the time when a new video tab is opened or reloaded (it always work on manually pressing play button).

```
video.onplay = function() {
console.log("onplay");
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({status: "played"});
};
```

Why is the onplay event unpredictable like this? Is there any way I can get this around or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Youtube is a dynamic (AJAX-driven) site so it updates the page on navigation within the site instead of reloading it. Content scripts run only on full page [re]load. Solutions are listed here: [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: Now I understand the problem. Thank you very much.